# Word for people who clean out supermarkets during crisis scares

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

What do you call the people who clean out the grocery stores when they hear the word *snow*?

Answer (score 7):

The action of cleaning out the stores is called [*panic buying*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panic_buying). The people who do it have been called *panic buyers*, although that's a less common expression.

Answer (score 1):

"hoarder" might be an alternative, depending on context.